# How to render HTML with event handling in an Angular component?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application with a component that contains a string variable holding HTML content. Within this HTML, there is a button with an event handler that calls the `foo()` function in the component.

My question is, how can I render this string variable in the template and ensure that the button click works within the Angular scope?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <!-- How can I render the string variable here? -->
    <!-- and ensure that the button click works within the Angular scope? -->
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    const string = `
      <div>
        <button (click)="foo()"></button>
      </div>
      <span>...</span>
    `;

    // What is the appropriate way to render this string into the template?
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('Inside foo!');
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arwkzv?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: What's the use case, don't you think its dangerous ?

Comment: I have html string from the server, and it contains many HTML tags and placeholders and I need to render the HTML and replace the placeholders with angular code. for example button which trigger a function, component with inputs: `"<foo [input]=".." >.."`.

Comment: Ok, AFAIK It won't be possible, as angular templates are compiled at build time. you will need to attach event listener by manually finding interactive elements by id (by using pure js)

Comment: Not necessarily for OP, but for anyone who is trying to do this for trivial reasons: This is a terrible idea. It should be a last resort when the business demands it and the tech debt would be to high to get out of this terrible, terrible pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the right function directly from your sanitized string with ease.
An alternative is to listen to the DOM and running the function when you click on the button.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="string"></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  string: SafeHtml = '';

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn: any) {
    if (btn instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
       this.foo()
    }
  }

constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.string =this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(  `
      <div>
        <button (click)="foo()">My Button</button>
      </div>
      <span>...</span>
    `);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('Inside foo!');
  }
}
```

EDIT, if you really want to bind with a function in your HTML, you can try to add the function into your class for example and to get it back afterward:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="string"></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  string: SafeHtml = '';

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn: HTMLElement) {
    if (btn instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
      const functions = btn.className
        .split(' ')
        .filter((cl) => cl.includes('function-'));
      if (functions.length > 0) {
        const fn = functions[0].split('function-')[1];
        (this as any)[fn](fn);
      }
    }
  }

  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.string = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
      <div>
        <button (click)="foo()" class="function-foo">Button</button>
      </div>
      <span>.Blob..</span>
    `);

    // What is the appropriate way to render this string into the template?
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('Inside foo!');
  }
}
```